# How to Achieve Word Wrap Effect With Children Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm currently working on a page that has a form (in an inline modal window ("Colobox" code)) with checkboxes, which, when clicked, append divs (that describe the checkbox checked) back to the parent div in the "parent" page.
My question is: how can I achieve a 'word wrap' effect with these child divs?
I have 3 parent divs to which the children are appended when a checkbox is checked.  However, I would like the .ksa_check_k class's divs to stay on one 'line div,' the .ksa_check_s class's divs to stay on one 'line div,' and the .ksa_check_a class's divs to stay on one 'line div.'
Also, is there a way to "order" the divs within each 'line,' according to a numeric value in each of the child divs' id, in order to compensate for 'out-of-numeric-order' clicking of the checkboxes?  [image: I've illustrated my desired effect below:]

Here is basic css, javascript and html form code (below).
The colorbox code files referenced can be found here: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Thanks for any help.

```
 <style>
    .inline_box{
    background-color:#FFCC00;
    padding:10px;  
    }

    tr.oddrow td {
    background-color: #eee;
    }

    .toBeCompared_k {
    display:block;
    background:red;
    }
    .toBeCompared_s {
    display:block;
    background:blue;
    }
    .toBeCompared_a {
    display:block;
    background:yellow;
    }
    .toBeCompared_new_k {
    display:block;
    background:red;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:2px;
    float:left;/**/
    }
    .toBeCompared_new_s {
    display:block;
    background:blue;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:2px;
    float:left;/**/
    }
    .toBeCompared_new_a {
    display:block;
    background:yellow;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:2px;
    float:left;/**/
    }
    .preview_notice {
    float:left;
    }
 </style>


<!--  Colorbox code - begin -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox/colorbox.css" />
<script src="overlay_2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script> 



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#colorbox, #cboxOverlay").appendTo('form:first');
            //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
            $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
            $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
            $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
            $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
            $(".ajax").colorbox();
            $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
            $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500, innerHeight:409});
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
            $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
            });

            $('.non-retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none'})
            $('.retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none', retinaImage:true, retinaUrl:true});

            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
            $("#click").click(function(){ 
                $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
<!-- Colorbox code - end -->

<!-- Function nth occurrence within string - begin -->
<script>
function nth_occurrence (string, char, nth) {
var first_index = string.indexOf(char);
var length_up_to_first_index = first_index + 1;

if (nth == 1) {
    return first_index;
} else {
    var string_after_first_occurrence = string.slice(length_up_to_first_index);
    var next_occurrence = nth_occurrence(string_after_first_occurrence, char, nth - 1);

    if (next_occurrence === -1) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return length_up_to_first_index + next_occurrence;  
    }
}
}


</script>
<!-- Function nth occurrence within string - end -->

<!-- Function show div elements - begin -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".ksa_check_k, .ksa_check_s, .ksa_check_a").click(function(){

if ($("#ksaChecks input:checkbox:checked").length > 0)
{

if ($('div.toBeCompared_pre').css('display') == 'none')
{
$('div.toBeCompared_pre').show();
}
if ($('div.preview_notice').css('display') == 'none')
{
$('div.preview_notice').show();
}
// any one is checked


}
else
{
// none is checked
if ($('div.toBeCompared_pre').css('display') == 'block') 
{
$('div.toBeCompared_pre').hide();
}
if ($('div.preview_notice').css('display') == 'block')
{
$('div.preview_notice').hide();
}
}

});

});
</script>
<!-- Function show div elements - end -->


<!-- Function to put 'preview' of selected ksa on page - begin -->
<script>
//code to put 'preview' of selected ksa on page
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ksa_check_k").click({param1: "k", param2: "World"}, cool_function2);
$(".ksa_check_s").click({param1: "s", param2: "World"}, cool_function2);
$(".ksa_check_a").click({param1: "a", param2: "World"}, cool_function2);


function cool_function2(event){

var ksa_section=event.data.param1

var title = $(this).closest('.ksa_check_group').find('.ksa_check_'+ksa_section).attr("id")

var title_partial = title.substring(nth_occurrence(title,'_',2)+1,nth_occurrence(title,'_',3))

if($(this).prop('checked')){

var html = '<div id="' + title_partial + '"class="toBeCompared_new_' + ksa_section + '">' + title_partial + '</div>';



$('div.toBeCompared_' + ksa_section).append(html);

$('div.toBeCompared_' + ksa_section).show();

} else {
$('div[id="' + title_partial + '"]').remove();


}
}
});
</script>
<!-- Function to put 'preview' of selected ksa on page - end -->



<table>
<tr>
<td>

<p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content_k">Add/Edit KSAs</a></p>





     <div class="toBeCompared_pre" style='display:none'>The following KSAs have been added: </div>

     <div class="toBeCompared_k"></div>
     <div class="toBeCompared_s"></div>
     <div class="toBeCompared_a"></div>


     <div class="preview_notice" style='display:none'>Important - Data Has Not Been Saved Yet.  Please click on the 'Update' button below to save your work.</div>






<div style='display:none'>

        <div id='inline_content_k'  class='inline_box'>




<table>
<!-- ////////////// 'k' section -->
<tr>
<td>

<div class="ksa_check_group">

<input name="ksa_on_1k1_1" id="ksa_on_1k1_1" type="checkbox" value="1" class="ksa_check_k">

</div>

<input name="ksa_off_1k1_1" id="ksa_off_1k1_1" type="hidden" value="0" class="ksa_check_k">
</div>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

<div class="ksa_check_group">

<input name="ksa_on_1k2_2" id="ksa_on_1k2_2" type="checkbox" value="1" class="ksa_check_k">

</div>

<input name="ksa_off_1k2_2" id="ksa_off_1k2_2" type="hidden" value="0" class="ksa_check_k">
</div>

</td>
</tr>
<!-- ////////////// 's' section -->
<tr>
<td>

<div class="ksa_check_group">

<input name="ksa_on_1s1_1" id="ksa_on_1s1_1" type="checkbox" value="1" class="ksa_check_s">

 </div>

<input name="ksa_off_1s1_1" id="ksa_off_1s1_1" type="hidden" value="0" class="ksa_check_s">
</div>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

<div class="ksa_check_group">

<input name="ksa_on_1s2_2" id="ksa_on_1s2_2" type="checkbox" value="1" class="ksa_check_s">

</div>

<input name="ksa_off_1s2_2" id="ksa_off_1s2_2" type="hidden" value="0" class="ksa_check_s">
</div>

</td>
</tr>
<!-- ////////////// 'a' section -->
<tr>
<td>

<div class="ksa_check_group">

<input name="ksa_on_1a1_1" id="ksa_on_1a1_1" type="checkbox" value="1" class="ksa_check_a">

</div>

<input name="ksa_off_1a1_1" id="ksa_off_1a1_1" type="hidden" value="0" class="ksa_check_a">
</div>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

<div class="ksa_check_group">

<input name="ksa_on_1a2_2" id="ksa_on_1a2_2" type="checkbox" value="1" class="ksa_check_a">

</div>

<input name="ksa_off_1a2_2" id="ksa_off_1a2_2" type="hidden" value="0" class="ksa_check_a">
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>


</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Since you already use the "float" keyword in your css code I'd imagine you are familiar with it, but are you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

jsfiddle example of what you could do: http://jsfiddle.net/qXWGW/ (fixed the link, sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too difficult to get what you're asking for as far as the display. You can use `float: left;` or `display: inline-block;`

I have included a fiddle with an example of getting this layout. The script also shows how you can sort the divs within each row. You may put this into a separate function to sort whenever you add a new element. Note that this is not the most efficient way since you're sorting things that may not need to be sorted, so if you have a lot of elements, you'll want to optimize this by only sorting the row you're adding to, or just inserting the new child directly into its correct position.

Also, I'm sorting based on the text in this example, but you could easily sort on a value store in a particular input field within the child, on an attribute on the child itself, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/s95BB/

```
$(function () {
    $(".row").each(function () {
        var children = $(".child", this).sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
        });
        $(this).append(children);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and ideas.  How would the new child be inserted into its correct position?  Would that involve a looping/scan of the form elements upon each click, etc?

Comment: Yup, you would loop through each form element and insert as you found the correct position. Here's an updated fiddle illustrating (I'm just adding to the first row for simplicity) http://jsfiddle.net/s95BB/1/ Also, if my answer provided you with the solution you're looking for, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As part of your solution I would opt for child spans, not divs. **span** tags will automatically flow and wrap.